# How can I create a legend of an envelope plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, legend

I making envelope plots which shows the minimum median max of my values. but when i try to create a legend it doesnt pick the median which has the right color as seen in the image below:

[image]

MWE for your perusal. Please help. link to data file: [Vani_fixed_10.dat](https://www.sendspace.com/file/cucw5q)

```
 \documentclass[preview,convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}
\begin{document}
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        ticklabel style = {font=\small},
        ytick={1,1.e-2,1.e-4,1.e-6,1.e-8,1.e-10,1.e-12},
        ymax=1,
        ymin=1.e-15,
        xmin=1,
        xmax=30,
        xlabel=\large{CPU (s)},
        ylabel=\large{RMSE},
        ]
 
    % vani
    \addplot+[name path=A,red!80!black,opacity=0.3,mark=none] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Off_min_Vani, col sep=space]{Vani_fixed_10.dat};
    \addplot+[name path=B,red!80!black,opacity=0.3,mark=none]table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Off_max_Vani, col sep=space]{Vani_fixed_10.dat};
    \addplot[red!80!black,opacity=0.3] fill between[of=A and B];
    \addplot[red,line width=2pt] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Off_med_Vani, col sep=space]{Vani_fixed_10.dat}; 
        \legend{{Method 1}}
    
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\legend`-command expects the legend entries of every plot in the exact order they have been created by `\addplot`.
For your example `\legend{A, B, fill, Method 1}` would describe every `\addplot`-instance correctly.
If you want an instance of `\addplot` to be ignored in the legend, you have to add `forget plot` as an option.

```
 \documentclass[preview,convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}
\begin{document}
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        ticklabel style = {font=\small},
        ytick={1,1.e-2,1.e-4,1.e-6,1.e-8,1.e-10,1.e-12},
        ymax=1,
        ymin=1.e-15,
        xmin=1,
        xmax=30,
        xlabel=\large{CPU (s)},
        ylabel=\large{RMSE},
        ]
 
    % vani
    \addplot+[name path=A,red!80!black,opacity=0.3,mark=none, forget plot] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Off_min_Vani, col sep=space]{Vani_fixed_10.dat};
    \addplot+[name path=B,red!80!black,opacity=0.3,mark=none, forget plot]table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Off_max_Vani, col sep=space]{Vani_fixed_10.dat};
    \addplot[red!80!black,opacity=0.3, forget plot] fill between[of=A and B];
    \addplot[red,line width=2pt] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Off_med_Vani, col sep=space]{Vani_fixed_10.dat}; 
        \legend{{Method 1}}
    
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
} 

\end{document}
```

Disclaimer: I was not able to check if the above code compiles correctly, as I do not want to download files from external websites. Please provide a MWE the next time!

Something off-topic: Do not use `\resizebox` to scale figures/pictures/plots as this will also scale the font. Use the appropriate `width` option provided by pgfplots instead!

Comment: Awsome it works perfectly. Any idea how to pop-out the legend and place it outside the plot to the right?

Comment: nevermind i did it with:  legend pos=outer north east]. Thanks a lot for your help!